# replacing html content in code behind

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an html page for prview of mail functionality.I fetch this in an object of stringbuilder type in code behind and substitue values.

There is a particular row in the .htm file that I want to hide via code behind under particular situation . How can I find that row and hide.

.htm row:

```
<TR bgcolor="E96F00">
     <TD style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 14px; font-weight: Bold; color:White;">Course Content Link</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
     <TD style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px;">@CourseContent@<BR>&nbsp;</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
     <TD style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 14px; color:Red; font-weight:bold">Important: TD>
</TR>
```

code behind where I am trying to replace:

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["Type"].ToString() == "V")
{
     if (dt.Rows[0]["CourseContentPath"].ToString() != string.Empty)
     {
          x.Replace("@CourseContent@", "<A href='" + CourseContentLink + "' target=_blank onclick='window.open(this.href, this.target,'height=1000px,width=1000px'); 
          return false>Click here</A> to find the course content");
      }
}
if (dt.Rows[0]["Type"].ToString() == "A")
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide some thing you can try below simple logic

**HTML**

```
 <table>...
  <tr id="important">some TDs html</tr>
 </table>
```

Try converting this **string into XML document** in code behind and check the logic and remove the tr node with id=important

then again convert the Xml Document to string .

For string to XML conversion check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Will this helpful?

Comment: and how can we find tr node with this id?